# Using Parse, how do I set a column unique or at least check if it exists first?

Tags: database, facebook, unique, parse-platform

I have a table of 'words', and what I want to do is, if a user uses that word, insert it into the table. But, if it already exists, update the count on that word.

I don't see a way to actually set columns as unique..
That said, how do I avoid the race condition:

t1 - user1 checks if 'Love' is used. NO
t2 - user2 checks if 'Love' is used. NO
t3 - user1 adds 'Love'
t4 - user2 adds 'Love'

I do not want this to be in the database twice.  Anyway to accomplish this in Parse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ['exists' query](https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#queries-constraints) to check for objects which have the key set:

```
var Word = Parse.Object.extend("words");
var query = new Parse.Query(Word);
query.exists("Love");
query.find({
  success: function(results) {
    if(results.length === 0){
      // Insert a new word object with the 'Love' key set to 1
      var newWord = new Word();
      newWord.set('Love', 1);
      newWord.save(null, {
        success: function(newWord) {
          alert('New object created with objectId: ' + newWord.id);
        },
        error: function(newWord, error) {
          alert('Failed to create new object, with error code: ' + error.description);
        }
      });
    } else {
      // Get the existing word object and increment its 'Love' key by 1
      var existingWord = results[0];
      var currCount = existingWord.get('Love');
      existingWord.set('Love', currCount + 1);
      existingWord.save(null, {
        success: function(existingWord) {
          alert('Existing object saved with objectId: ' + newWord.id);
        },
        error: function(existingWord, error) {
          alert('Failed to save existing object, with error code: ' + error.description);
        }
      });
    }
  },
  error: function(error) {
    alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
  }
});
```

With regard to preventing race conditions, you could handle this with [Parse Cloud Code](https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide).  You could have a Cloud Function which handles the input of the data and it should handle the requests sequentially.

Comment: this answer looks right. why hasnt it been marked correct? Did it solve your problem @JP?

Comment: in the code, there is an extra equal sign in `if(results.length === 0)`

Comment: Yes, in JavaScript === compares the value and type.  See this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons

Comment: This code doesn't work if more than one requests executed concurrently.

Comment: The check routine must be in the server side, not in the client side. I think the best solution is to use **CloudCode** or **Database UNIQUE KEY** to prevent saving duplicates.

Answer (score 5):

To avoid race conditions, you should make the column/field unique. Do that in the database that you use with with Parse (if you use mongoDB with your parse server, then here's a link for mongoDB for example - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/).  Then in CloudCode - try to create a new word object and store it.  If the word already exists, the store will fail and then you can use a query to find the existing word and increment instead.